# How can I use grep with all available cores?

Tags: linux, bash, optimization, grep, find

**Problem:** We know the string to look for but do not know which file to look in.

for example..

say we have a file that contains the following.

```
blah blah blah
....
IMPORTANT NOTE: very important note
.....
blah blah blah blah
```

we do not know the file name (there could be multiple files with the same "IMPORTANT NOTE" tag) and we want to find all of the files that contain an "IMPORTANT NOTE"

**One Solution:**

```
 find /directory/to/search/ -exec grep "IMPORTANT NOTE" {} /dev/null \;
```

I would use this for scripting because I can capture the filenames and do stuff with it.

**Another Solution:**

```
 grep -R "IMPORTANT NOTE" /directory/to/search/*
```

I would use this to manually look for a file..

From what I understand, the above runs on one process and uses a single core. can this be modified to execute each file search  as a separate task to make use of all available cores on the machine? (kind of like a forkbomb<sup>1)</sup> I know you can execute a command in the background by using &, can this be used? if so how do I make sure the parent shell keeps a handle on the output of the commands?

1) [fork bomb](https://www.incapsula.com/ddos/attack-glossary/fork-bomb.html) - easy denial of service "attack"

IMPORTANT NOTE: This will completely lock up your machine. (try it out in a virtual machine you don't care about)

Syntax for fork bomb:

```
 :(){ : | :& }; :
```

Comment: why you want to use all the core?

Comment: I just want to see if I can make it run faster by using all processing power.

Comment: Well after 2-3 instances it will become memory bound, and probably earlier disk bound, unless you have a really big system.

Comment: What do fork bombs have to do with your question? This seems to ramble quite a lot, rather than asking a single tightly-scoped thing. And we need locked-down details (ie. if you're searching one file or several) to be able to evaluate answers' correctness.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
grep -R "IMPORTANT NOTE" /directory/to/search/[a-m]* &
grep -R "IMPORTANT NOTE" /directory/to/search/[n-z]* &
```

note this doesn't cover all files.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xargs -P` lets you control how many instances are concurrently run, kicking off new ones whenever others die.

```
find /directory/to/search/ -print0 \
| xargs -P 8 grep -n 1 -e "IMPORTANT NOTE" /dev/null
```

That said -- in general, this will be I/O rather than CPU-bound; you should be worried about maxing out your disk bandwidth, not your CPU cores.